# Magento - Add default filter to product collection

Tags: magento, filter, php

Working with a client who saw this site and would like something similar.

http://www.boylstontradingco.com/shop/sale

As you can see when you browse to the "sale" category a "sale" filter is activated by default in the layered navigation on the left.  I know that part of the layered navigation pulls its info from a function called getActiveFilters().  Is there a way to add an active filter by default in the code or through the admin?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_category');
$item = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_item');
$model->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter(
  $item->setFilter($model)
       ->setLabel('Sale')
);
```

Comment: I did figure out how to implement this by adding it to the file state.phtml though it doesn't seem to be filtering on the items that are on sale. Right now I have an attribute called sale which is a drop down with 2 options 1 being "On Sale" and the other being "Full Price".  I changed the code you gave me to:  $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_category');
 $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_item');
 $model->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter(
   $item->setFilter($model)
        ->setLabel('On Sale')
 );

Comment: More specifically what I need to do is to create an instance where all products on the site are added to a collection and then filtered based on if they items have a special price. When the user is viewing the page "Sale".  The trick is that the layered navigation still needs to work.